# How to write this query in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two columns (both primary) [PLAYER_ID] [LEAUGE_ID]

something like this:

```
Player_id      League_id
2139            8
2153            8
2302            10
2441            8
2441            10  
2441            16
```

I am trying to find the same player who played only in leages 8 and 10, so although 2441 played for 16, we need to omit that.

According to the table above, I am trying to only find:

```
Player_id     League_id_1     League_id_2
2441          8               10
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you need playes that played *at least* in 8 and 10 and just don't show other records (for the same player) ?

Comment: You also need the query to transpose the rows into columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select t1.player_id, t1.league_id league_id_1, t2.league_id league_id_2
  from table1 t1
  join table1 t2 on t1.player_id = t2.player_id
 where t1.league_id = 8
   and t2.league_id = 10
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbbb0/3) is a fiddle

Comment: @a.b The query I eventually wanted was a pain in the ass! but this was a great help! thanks again!